# How to refactor custom hook that returns values, functions, and *components*?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that has a bunch of related values and functions that returns a component that requires those values and functions. Currently, I have it in a single hook because it is much cleaner than the alternative.

I've placed random numbers for illustration.

**OPTION 1: currently preferred single cleaner hook that returns components**

```js
const customHook = ({ dep1, dep2, ...deps}) => {
   // a bunch of related stuff
   return {
      val1,
      ...,
      val9,
      func1,
      ...,
      func5,
      component1: val3 && <Component1 val1={val1} ..... val6={val6} />,
      component2: val5 && <Component2 val1={val1} ..... val6={val6} func1={func1} ... func={func5}/>
   }
}

// component
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { ...vals, component1, component2 }= cusotmHook({ ...deps})

  return (
     <Stuff>
       {component1}
       {component2}
     </Stuff>
  )
}
```

**OPTION 2: alternative to use hook and create components separately**

```js
import customHook from './customHook'
import {Component1, Component2} from './Components'
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { vals.... } = customHook({ ...deps })

  return (
     <Stuff>
       <Component1 {...listOfValuesFromHook} />
       <Component2 {...listOfValuesFromHook} />
     </Stuff>
  )
}
```

**I find option 2 to be more cumbersome (obviously simplified for our situation), is this too much of an anti-pattern? Is there a better way to keep it clean without having to pass a large props array to component1, 2, etc.?**

Comment: Instead of a custom hook, why not just make it an element instead? Since it's purpose is to produce an element.

Comment: @HaoWu the purpose is to produce values, functions, and components. My illustration doesn't show all that, just the component part for simplicity but does show the values being deconstructed to demonstrate usage